# Font change in latex - Titlepage

Tags: fonts

Im having a problem, probably is that i really dont understand how fonts work in latex. The problem is that i have a font in my title page, and other in the rest of the file. I leave a reduction of the code. I remove a some lines thats have nothing to do with fonts.

Why its having two fonts?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, spanish]{report} % Documento two sided
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{graphicx} % paquete para ver imagenes
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames,svgnames,nonamebreak,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} % si lo pongo antes de xcolor crashea

\title{Thesis Title}
\author{name}
\date{1 09 2020}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\chapter*{Resumen}
\input{resumen}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduccion}
\input{chapters/Introduccion}


\end{document}
```

And the title

```
\begin{titlepage}

\newgeometry{,width=140mm,top=32mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
     \draw[frenchblue!100!black,line width=12pt] ([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=-3cm]current page.north west) coordinate(A)--([xshift=2.5cm,yshift=3cm]current page.south west) coordinate (B)--cycle;

   \end{tikzpicture}

        \vspace*{-1cm}

        \Huge
        \noindent\color{frenchblue}\textbf{blablabla }

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \LARGE
        %Tesis sub titulo

        \vspace{1.5cm}
        \color{black}
        \textbf{blabla}

        \vfill

        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{blabl}

        \Large
        \noindent blablabla

        \vspace{0.8cm}



        \large
        Septiembre 2020

\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! If you put `\fontname\font` in various places, you will see the font is all the same: lmroman, which is the default if no roman font is set. Inconsolata sets the sans family, but the example does not typeset any sans text. What font should be there?

Comment: You are right, thx to you i realice what was going on. I defined with titleformat, the color and thing to the chapter and section name, and there i have use the sans family, and so thats why i was seeing different fonts!!!